# create additional new functions of a compiled library

Tags: opencv, static-libraries

I'm using OpenCV API. The libraries such as cv, cxcore, highgui are already compiled and added to my new applications. In this case, if I want to write additional functions and add them to these classes or modify some functions in orginal source files without having to recompile those libraries. Is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, **when you change the source code you need to recompile** the libraries for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've made my question clear yet. But I dont' really want to change the compiled libraries, but the class itself. So that, in new projects, I want to use those added functions, I just have to add the compiled library, my code (for the additional funcs in the compiled class), and invoke the class to use.

Comment: I understand, but as far as I know you'll need to recompile the libraries again.